# error C2352 illegal call of non-static member function

Tags: c++, arrays, unit-testing, testing, priority-queue

I am creating a Heap type priority queue using a dynamically sized array. I am aware that vectors would be simpler to implement, but this is a learning exercise for me. Everything works great, but I am having issues only when attempting some Unit testing in visual studio '13.  I'm experiencing [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS5m1.png)

Here is the source file  where I attempt to run the Unit tests:

```
//Prog1Test.cpp
#include "UnitTest.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    PriorityQueue Q = PriorityQueue();
    UnitTest::test1(Q);
    UnitTest::test2(Q);
    UnitTest::test3(Q);
    UnitTest::test4(Q);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the UnitTest.cpp:

```
//UnitTest.cpp
#include "UnitTest.h"
#include <cassert>

void UnitTest::test1(PriorityQueue Q)
{
    Q.clear();
    Q.append('a');
    Q.append('b');
    assert(Q.size() == 2);
    assert(Q.check() == true);
}

void UnitTest::test2(PriorityQueue Q)
{
    Q.clear();
    Q.append('b');
    Q.append('a');
    assert(Q.size() == 2);
    assert(Q.check() == false);
}

void UnitTest::test3(PriorityQueue Q)
{
    Q.clear();
    Q.insert('a');
    Q.insert('b');
    assert(Q.size() == 2);
    assert(Q.check() == true);
    assert(Q.remove() == 'a');
    assert(Q.size() == 1);
}

void UnitTest::test4(PriorityQueue Q)
{
    Q.clear();
    Q.insert('b');
    Q.insert('a');
    assert(Q.size() == 2);
    assert(Q.check() == true);
    assert(Q.remove() == 'a');
    assert(Q.size() == 1);
}
```

Here is the UnitTest header file:

```
//UnitTest.h
#ifndef UnitTest_H
#define UnitTest_H
#include "PriorityQueue.h"

class UnitTest
{
public:
    void test1(PriorityQueue Q);
    void test2(PriorityQueue Q);
    void test3(PriorityQueue Q);
    void test4(PriorityQueue Q);
};


#endif
```

Here is the PriorityQueue class header:

```
#ifndef PriorityQueue_H
#define PriorityQueue_H

class PriorityQueue
{
private:
    char *pq;
    int length;
    int nextIndex;
    char root;
public:
    PriorityQueue();
    ~PriorityQueue();
    char& operator[](int index);
    void append(char val);
    int size();
    void clear();
    void heapify();
    bool check();
    void insert(char val);
    char remove();
    friend class UnitTest;
};


#endif
```

here is the priorityqueue.cpp file:

```
#include<math.h>
#include "PriorityQueue.h"




PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue()
{
    pq = new char[0];
    this->length = 0;
    this->nextIndex = 0;
}




PriorityQueue::~PriorityQueue() {
    delete[] pq;
}




char& PriorityQueue::operator[](int index) {
    char *pnewa;
    if (index >= this->length) {
        pnewa = new char[index + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->nextIndex; i++)
            pnewa[i] = pq[i];
        for (int j = this->nextIndex; j < index + 1; j++)
            pnewa[j] = 0;
        this->length = index + 1;
        delete[] pq;
        pq = pnewa;
    }
    if (index > this->nextIndex)
        this->nextIndex = index + 1;
    return *(pq + index);
}




void PriorityQueue::append(char val) {
    char *pnewa;
    if (this->nextIndex == this->length) {
        this->length = this->length + 1;
        pnewa = new char[this->length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->nextIndex; i++)
            pnewa[i] = pq[i];
        for (int j = this->nextIndex; j < this->length; j++)
            pnewa[j] = 0;
        delete[] pq;
        pq = pnewa;
    }
    pq[this->nextIndex++] = val;
}



int PriorityQueue::size() {
    return this->length;
}




void PriorityQueue::clear() {
    delete[] pq;
    pq = new char[0];
    this->length = 0;
    this->nextIndex = 0;
}




void PriorityQueue::heapify() {
    char parent;
    char root;
    char temp;
    for (double i = this->length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        root = pq[0];
        int parentindex = floor((i - 1) / 2);
        int leftchildindex = 2 * i + 1;
        int rightchildindex = 2 * i + 2;
        if (pq[(int)i] <= pq[leftchildindex] && pq[(int)i] <= pq[rightchildindex])
        {
            pq[(int)i] = pq[(int)i];
        }
        else if (rightchildindex < this->length && pq[(int)i] > pq[rightchildindex])
        {
            temp = pq[(int)i];
            pq[(int)i] = pq[rightchildindex];
            pq[rightchildindex] = temp;
            heapify();
        }
        else if (leftchildindex < this->length && pq[(int)i] > pq[leftchildindex])
        {
            temp = pq[(int)i];
            pq[(int)i] = pq[leftchildindex];
            pq[leftchildindex] = temp;
            heapify();
        }
    }
}



void PriorityQueue::insert(char val) {
    char *pnewa;
    if (this->nextIndex == this->length) {
        this->length = this->length + 1;
        pnewa = new char[this->length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->nextIndex; i++)
            pnewa[i] = pq[i];
        for (int j = this->nextIndex; j < this->length; j++)
            pnewa[j] = 0;
        delete[] pq;
        pq = pnewa;
    }
    pq[this->nextIndex++] = val;
    PriorityQueue::heapify();
}


bool PriorityQueue::check() {
    char root;
    root = pq[0];
    for (int i = this->length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((int)pq[i]< (int)root)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}



char PriorityQueue::remove() {
    char root = pq[0];
    char *qminus;
    qminus = new char[this->length];
    for (int i = 1; i<this->length; i++)
        qminus[i - 1] = pq[i];
    pq = qminus;
    this->length -= 1;
    PriorityQueue::heapify();
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag questions about `c++` as `c`.

Comment: sorry! first time poster.

Answer (score 3):

you need to declare your test methods as `static`

```
class UnitTest
{
public:
    static void test1(PriorityQueue Q);
    static void test2(PriorityQueue Q);
    static void test3(PriorityQueue Q);
    static void test4(PriorityQueue Q);
};
```

Note that the `static` methods can only refer to static data members, since there is no class instance when calling these methods.

Answer (score 1):

you need an instance of `UnitTest`

```
PriorityQueue Q = PriorityQueue();
UnitTest t;
t.test1(Q);
t.test2(Q);
t.test3(Q);
t.test4(Q);
return 0;
```

Note that currently there's no good reason why your test functions are part of a class altogether.

Comment: Consider placing test functions in a class as an organization tool, similar to using a namespace.   This is also a common OOP technique.

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers are correct, a `static` or using object may solve the problem.

Another solution is to use `namespace` instead of `class`:

```
namespace UnitTest
{
    void test1(PriorityQueue Q);
    void test2(PriorityQueue Q);
    void test3(PriorityQueue Q);
    void test4(PriorityQueue Q);
};
```

Comment: I would like to use your method, but I'm getting the error that "a symbol with this name already exists and therefore this name cannot be used as a namespace name". any advice?

Comment: you should first remove the class or change its name.